# MS Access Web App: set filter on sub view based on master view

Tags: sharepoint-2013, ms-access-2013

My application has a list view (master) containing a data sheet view in a sub view element.
In the list view, I would like to use some control like a button or a combo box to filter the data in the sub view. How can I pass a parameter for the filter from the master view to the sub view?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe the scenario you are looking at here will be directly possible within the Access web app context. Let me explain.

In Access 2013 web apps, there is no macro action available to requery or refresh a specific control on a view. The same goes for trying to refresh a Subview control on a view. The only way you can pass parameters to a different view in the web app context is by using the OpenPopup macro action. In that case the view will open as a popup which is not what you want here either.

So you might not be able to achieve your end goal. One suggestion that *might* work is to have say an unbound text box control on the main parent view. For the Subview control, use that unbound control as the Master Field (in the property list). Access will attempt to match records from this unbound control to whatever field you designate as the Child Field property. If you update that unbound text box control on the main view, Access should filter the results in the Subview. I "think" that will work.

Answer (score 0):

It works in my app.  SubForm updates with filter when focus leaves the txtbox.  Unfortunately, you can only search one field per subview as it is set as a property at design time and AFAIK there is no way to change at runtime.